# How do I filter off a separate attribute in a ssas parent-child hierarchy?

Tags: ssas, parent-child, hierarchy, olap, dimensions

I have a parent-child hierarchy based on departments and sub-departments in a Department dimension.

There is a separate field that is a flag I want to slice this data on in my cube. How do I configure the dimension so that field is visible?

I have it set up as a regular attribute, with AttributeHierarchyVisible true, but when I view the dimension in the cube browser, it's nowhere to be found.

I tried creating a user-defined hierarchy from the flag to my departments, and it still does not appear. If I click "Show all attributes" it will appear under the description of the member, but it is unavailable for filtering.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can correclty reference the flag for filtering?

Answer (score 0):

You should only need a regular attribute.  I have a similar dimension design in one cube and it works fine.  I can see and use it in the BIDS Dimension Browser and in the BIDS Cube Browser, and in Excel 2010 Pivot Tables.

Comment: That's what I would have thought, too, as it behaves that way when in a non parent-child dimension. In this case it just doesn't show up.

Comment: Are you using Perspectives?

Comment: No, straight off the cube here.

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange. On the dimension page itself, have you tried processing the dimension and then browsing the dimension on its own. If you don't see it there, I would drop and recreate the dimension all together.